# Incorrect date being displayed in Flot tooltip

Tags: javascript, date, flot

Let's start with the code in question:

```
<div id="debug"></div><br />
<div id="placeholder" class="demo-placeholder"></div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/doppelog/static/doppelog/js/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/doppelog/static/doppelog/js/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() 
    {
        var alc = 
        {
            label:"ALC", data:
            [
                [1.3765428e+12,2],

                [1.3775796e+12,88],

                [1.377666e+12,109],

                [1.3777524e+12,65],
            ]
        };

        var options = 
        {
            //points: {show:true},
            bars: {show:true, fill: .65, barWidth:0.85*24*60*60*1000}, //leading co-efficient for bar width, other scalars to get to 1 day resolution
            xaxis: 
            {
                mode: "time",
                timeformat: "%Y-%m-%d",
                autoscaleMargin: null
            },
            grid: {hoverable:true}

        };

        function showTooltip(x, y, contents) {
            $("<div id='tooltip'>" + contents + "</div>").css({
                position: "absolute",
                display: "none",
                top: y + 5,
                left: x + 5,
                border: "1px solid #fdd",
                padding: "2px",
                "background-color": "#fee",
                opacity: 0.80
            }).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
        };

        var previousPoint = null;
        $("#placeholder").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) 
        {

            if (item) 
            {
                if (previousPoint != item.dataIndex) 
                {

                    previousPoint = item.dataIndex;

                    $("#tooltip").remove();
                    var x = item.datapoint[0],
                    y = item.datapoint[1],
                    d = new Date(x),
                    td = d.getFullYear() + "-" + d.getMonth() + "-" + d.getDay();
                    document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML=x;
                    showTooltip(item.pageX, item.pageY, td + ": " + y);
                }
            } 
            else 
            {
                $("#tooltip").remove();
                previousPoint = null;            
            }
        });

        $.plot("#placeholder", [alc], options);
        //document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML=alc[1];
    });

</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XBCvq/

The date labels on the x axis are correct. On mouseover, the value of x is displayed in the div up top. When you copy that into a Javascript console as "new Date(x)", the correct date is generated.

When you mouse over a bar, a date that's off by more than a month appears. Why is that, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the discrepancy is due to the fact that months (as returned by getMonth) start at zero, and the rest is because you aren't taking into account the UTC offset.

It's much easier to re-use Flot's own formatDate function, like this:

```
var DATE_FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%d";  // Use this in your plot options as well
...
showTooltip(item.pageX, item.pageY, $.plot.formatDate(d, DATE_FORMAT) + ":" + y);
```

Comment: There was no embedded timezone information (checked that), but the month problem was spot on. Also, turns out that getDay() gets a number for day of the week, unlike getDate(). Thanks!